# bin bash script that takes the name of such a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Each line always consists of two columns.

In each column I have two strings separated by a space.

How I can write a script that takes the name of such a file as the first argument and calculates the sum on subsequent pairs of numbers read from our file.

I have to display information about errors - why the given line can not be processed, if such a situation occurred

So for example I have:

```
100 300
20 10
11 0 
55
11 11a11
333 3
```

Comment: How's your progress on the implementation so far?

Comment: What part of the script are you running into problems with? Accessing file variables? Making calculations? Error detecting and processing? Can you provide an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implementation:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [[ ! -z ${line} ]]; then
        echo "Processing line: \"${line}\":"

        v1=$(awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }' <<< ${line})
        v2=$(awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }' <<< ${line})

        if [ -z "${v1}" ] || [ -z "${v2}" ]; then
            echo " > Invalid provided value(s)!"
        else
            result=$(expr ${v1} + ${v2})

            if [[ ! -z ${result} ]]; then
                echo " > Result of ${v1} + ${v2} is ${result}."
            else
                echo " > Sum failed!"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done < {{YOUR_INPUT_FILE}}
```

Please, remember to replace the `{{YOUR_INPUT_FILE}}` variable.

Comment: This may help for future scripts: `while read -r v1 v2; do echo "$v1 $v2"; done < file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk ' {
      if($1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/)  { print "line "NR": error: col 1 not valid"; next}
      if($2 !~ /^[0-9]+$/)  { print "line "NR": error: col 2 not valid"; next}
      print "line "NR": " $1+$2
}' $1


$ ./script.sh file.txt
line 1: 400
line 2: 30
line 3: 11
line 4: error: col 2 not valid
line 5: error: col 2 not valid
line 6: 336
```